PCI-3 nvme 2 SSD Expansion Card Not Showing On BIOS and Explorer and Disk Management
My setup:
MSI B550 Tomahawk (https://download.msi.com/archive/mnu_exe/mb/MAGB550TOMAHAWK.pdf)
M2_1= 970 EVO Plus 2b
M2_2= 970 EVO PLUS 1B
SATA SSD= 870 EVO 500 GB
PCIE-3= 970 EVO PLUS 1GB (Not Empty)
(https://www.amazon.com.tr/dp/B09JP8YSHB/ref=asc_df_B09JP8YSHB1715310240000/)
As I learned later NGFF is for SATA connection. I am struggling with this setup for a day.
My PCIE-3 M2 SSD card not shows up in BIOS, Device Manager and Disk Management but weird the expansion card's blue light is turn on.
If possible can someone please help ne how can fix my this issue?
P.S.: My PCI-E2 slot is empty because in manual it says "When installing devices in M.2_2, PCI_E2 & PCI_E3 slots at the same time, PCI_E3 slot will be unavailable, and M2_2 slot only supports PCIe x2." Please refer page to 16.
